# Create a buffer and assign it a pointer in Python

Tags: python, c, swig

I have a small application written in Python. It needs to take a user input(from cmd line):

```
def wr(input=0):   
    p = struct_t() # a C struct
    p.data = input # p.data is a pointer
    c_function(p)
```

Here data can be up to 32 words. And the `data` field of struct `struct_t` is of type `uint32_t *`.

The above code gives me an error of unmatched types for `p.data = input`. What I want is to have a buffer in Python that takes the user input and let the pointer `p.data` point to that buffer, so that I can pass `p` to my C routine.

I know that I can create a string buffer and cast it to type `uint32_t *` with ctypes in a very straightforward way, but I wonder if there's a way to do it in SWIG. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you want the type of `input` to be? It's easy if it's a list of ints.

Comment: @Flexo I think just ints, like input=479825793457392574390954370… (something very long, upto 32 words size) Thanks.

Comment: well that would never fit in a 32 bit int.

Comment: @rowan.G Yeah, thanks for pointing it out. Then I suppose it should be a list of ints. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use SWIG to connect your Python script with C project, the first step is to create an interface file that includes the C functions that will be called by Python (i.e., interface functions), such as *buffer.i* as follows.

```
/* File: buffer.i */
%module buffer

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "buffer.h"
%}

void wr(int idx, unsigned int val);
unsigned int rd(int idx);
```

It's a good practice to keep the interface simple, and leave the complexity to C running in the background. Accordingly, you can manually create a C header file (*buffer.h*) and implementation file (*buffer.c*), as follows.

Here is *buffer.h*

```
/* File: buffer.h */

#include <stdint.h>

void wr(int idx, unsigned int val);
unsigned int rd(int idx);
```

Here is *buffer.c*

```
/* File: buffer.c */

#include "buffer.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 32

unsigned int buf[BUF_SIZE];

void wr(int idx, unsigned int val) {
  buf[idx%BUF_SIZE] = val;
}

unsigned int rd(int idx) {
  return buf[idx%BUF_SIZE];
}
```

And you'll need a setup file (*setup.py*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
setup.py file for SWIG buffer
"""

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


buffer_module = Extension('_buffer',
                           sources=['buffer_wrap.c', 'buffer.c'],
                           )

setup (name = 'buffer',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "SWIG Docs",
       description = """Simple swig buffer from docs""",
       ext_modules = [buffer_module],
       py_modules = ["buffer"],
       )
```

Now you can use SWIG to build the project by issuing the following commands:

```
$ swig -python buffer.i
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The above commands will automatically generate *buffer.py*, which give you the caller framework (on Python side). Open this file, you'll see `_buffer.wr` and `_buffer.rd` already being created. In order to convert a very long int (Python style) 32 bits at a time and keep it in a C array, you can add a wrapper function in *buffer.py*, which calls the automatically generated Python function `wr` multiple times:

```
def wr1(args):
  for n in range(0, 32):
    val = args & 0xffffffff
    wr(n, val)
    args >>= 32
    if args == 0:
      break
```

Now you can run Python. Here is what you see when you run it:

```
>>> import buffer
>>> buffer.wr1(0x12345678deadbeef)
>>> hex(buffer.rd(0))
'0xdeadbeef'
>>> hex(buffer.rd(1))
'0x12345678'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But can you explain what is _buffer.wr and _buffer.rd? I still don't know how the c function is connected with Python. I don't need to modify the .i file for SWIG?

Comment: @JFreebird: Updated by giving more details.

Comment: BTW, here is a link to describe using SWIG for Python:http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html